# What are the parameters in signal recovery? Whether source of these parameters are the sampling property of impulse response?

Tags: signal-processing, signal-detection

I was reading the following book: Juditsky, Anatoli, and Arkadi Nemirovski. Statistical Inference via Convex Optimization. Vol. 69. Princeton University Press, 2020. Here, I could not visualize the appearance of parameters in the explanation attached (page no 2 of the first chapter). Is it true that parameters in signal recovery hidden in the sampling property of unite step impulse response?[image]